# In Spark I am not able to filter by existing column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter by one of the column in the dataframe using spark. But spark throws below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Inv. Pty' given input columns: [Pstng Date, Name 1, Inv. Pty, Year]

invDF.filter(col("Inv. Pty") === "2001075").show()
```

Comment: Can you print schema of your dataframe using printSchema and update the question with it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the backwards `

```
invDF.filter(col("`Inv. Pty`") === "2001075").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Spark assumes the column with "dot" as struct column.
To counter that, you need to use a backtick "`". This should work:

```
invDF.filter(col("`Inv. Pty`") === "2001075").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but given input columns: [Pstng Date, Name 1, Inv. Pty, Year] column has an extra space Inv. Pty,might be that is the problem.